# Link of class 'Lorg/opencv/javacv/facerecognition/FdActivity;' failed

Tags: java, android, eclipse, opencv

I'm trying to build this code : https://github.com/ayuso2013/face-recognition

I have successfully install OpenCV libraries like "Open CV Library" "JavaCV-Bin"

I can compile application successfully, but when I try to run it I get the errors below:

```
02-24 19:30:00.777: I/dalvikvm(13937): Failed resolving Lorg/opencv/javacv/facerecognition/FdActivity; interface 1202 'Lorg/opencv/android/CameraBridgeViewBase$CvCameraViewListener2;'
02-24 19:30:00.777: W/dalvikvm(13937): Link of class 'Lorg/opencv/javacv/facerecognition/FdActivity;' failed
02-24 19:30:00.777: D/AndroidRuntime(13937): Shutting down VM
02-24 19:30:00.777: W/dalvikvm(13937): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x411bfac8)
02-24 19:30:00.777: E/AndroidRuntime(13937): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-24 19:30:00.777: E/AndroidRuntime(13937): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{org.opencv.javacv.facerecognition/org.opencv.javacv.facerecognition.FdActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.opencv.javacv.facerecognition.FdActivity" on path: /data/app/org.opencv.javacv.facerecognition-2.apk
02-24 19:30:00.777: E/AndroidRuntime(13937):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
02-24 19:30:00.777: E/AndroidRuntime(13937):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
02-24 19:30:00.777: E/AndroidRuntime(13937):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:154)
02-24 19:30:00.777: E/AndroidRuntime(13937):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
02-24 19:30:00.777: E/AndroidRuntime(13937):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-24 19:30:00.777: E/AndroidRuntime(13937):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-24 19:30:00.777: E/AndroidRuntime(13937):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
02-24 19:30:00.777: E/AndroidRuntime(13937):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-24 19:30:00.777: E/AndroidRuntime(13937):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-24 19:30:00.777: E/AndroidRuntime(13937):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
02-24 19:30:00.777: E/AndroidRuntime(13937):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
02-24 19:30:00.777: E/AndroidRuntime(13937):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-24 19:30:00.777: E/AndroidRuntime(13937): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.opencv.javacv.facerecognition.FdActivity" on path: /data/app/org.opencv.javacv.facerecognition-2.apk
02-24 19:30:00.777: E/AndroidRuntime(13937):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
02-24 19:30:00.777: E/AndroidRuntime(13937):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
02-24 19:30:00.777: E/AndroidRuntime(13937):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
02-24 19:30:00.777: E/AndroidRuntime(13937):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1071)
02-24 19:30:00.777: E/AndroidRuntime(13937):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2166)
02-24 19:30:00.777: E/AndroidRuntime(13937):    ... 11 more
02-24 19:30:09.456: I/Process(13937): Sending signal. PID: 13937 SIG: 9
```

I can see this line

```
02-24 19:30:00.777: E/AndroidRuntime(13937): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.opencv.javacv.facerecognition.FdActivity" on path: /data/app/org.opencv.javacv.facerecognition-2.apk
```

But I'm sure that the file FdActivity.class is located in src/org/opencv/javacv/facerecognition/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share the execution command that you use?

Comment: @alainlompo how? I'm running it by clicking run button in Eclipse IDE.

Comment: OK. That answers my question. Thanks